# JavaScript - How to set innerHTML / value depending on element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Is there a way of setting an elements value by checking if it uses `innerHTML` or `value` to be set, bearing in mind that form elements are the only elements to take `value`, for example:

```
if(elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" || elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") //e.t.c
{
    elem.innerHTML = "Blah blah blah";
}
else
{
    elem.value = "Blah blah blah";
}
```

Would I have to do this for each element which is not a form element, or is there a better way?

Comment: AFAIK only input, textarea and select options have values. so u can check for those

Comment: Not all form elements has a `value` property. Textarea for example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

```
if(elem.innerHTML) {
 elem.innerHTML = 'blah blah blah';
}
else {
 elem.value = 'other blah blah';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tagNameValues{
    "INPUT": "value",
    "TEXTAREA": "value",
    "SELECT": "value",
    "DIV": "innerHTML",
    "TH":"innerHTML",
    "TD":"innerHTML"
}
elem[tagNameValues[elem.tagName]] = "Blah blah blah";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
var putValue = function (elem, value) {
  if(elem.value === undefined) {
    elem.innerHTML = value;
  } else {
    elem.value = value;    
  }
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/egINEJU/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var assignValue = function (elem, value) {
try{
  elem.innerHTML=value;
  elem.value=value;
}catch(e){
  elem.value=value;
 }
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iKOBONe/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

You can check is the value property exists and act accordingly, like so:

```
if (elem.value) {
    elem.value = "some value";
} else {
    elem.innerHTML = "some value";
}
```

Here is a shorter version, if you prefer that:

```
elem[elem.value ? "value" : "innerHTML"] = "some value";
```